# NullPointerException with a bank account in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get this Exception when I try to create a new customer in my bank account program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bank.program.Customer.addAccount(Customer.java:18)
    at bank.program.BankProgram.main(BankProgram.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

What does it mean, and what do I need to change to get rid of it?

`Bank` class:

```
public class Bank {
    String bankName;    
    private ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();  

    Bank(String bankName) {
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer newCustomer) {
        customers.add(newCustomer);
    }
}
```

`Account` class:

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected double balance = 0;
    protected String accountId;

    public Account() {}  //Defaultkonstruktor

    public Account(double bal, String id) {   //Konstruktor
        if (balance >= 0) {
           balance = bal;
        }
        else {
            balance = 0;
        }
        accountId = id;
    }

    public abstract void deposit(double amount);    

    public abstract void withdraw(double amount);

    public abstract double getBalance();

    public abstract String getAccountId();

    public void transfer(double amount, Account account) {
        account.deposit(amount);
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

`SavingsAccount` class:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
    private double interest = 2.9;

    public SavingsAccount() {     
        super();
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double bal, String id) {   
        super(bal, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void deposit(double amount) {

    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(double amount) {

    }

    @Override  
    public double getBalance() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getAccountId() {

    }
}
```

`Customer` class:

```
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String number;      
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;

    Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String number) { 
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void addAccount(SavingsAccount account) {
        accounts.add(account);
    }

    public ArrayList<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

Bank program class:

```
public class BankProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfCustomers = 0;
        Bank bank = new Bank("Bank name");

        System.out.print("Enter amount to deposit: ");
        double amount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Account number: " + numberOfCustomers);
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String firstName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        String lastName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Customer number: ");
        String pnumber = input.next();

        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(firstName, lastName, pnumber);        
        SavingsAccount savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(amount, "11");
        newCustomer.addAccount(savingsAccount);
        bank.addCustomer(newCustomer);           
    }    
}
```

Comment: user, in the future, when asking questions about errors or exceptions, please help us out and indicate to us just where the error is occurring. Your error or exception message will tell you this exactly, and only you can find out where it is, not us. Also and more importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should inspect the line carefully that throws the exception**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: See my updated comment

Comment: You've got a correct answer, and again this comment is for future questions, but still in your question above, nowhere do you indicate which line is the offending line. Yes, we can try to count lines, but it is cumbersome, prone to errors, and we may not be correct even if our count is accurate, because we have no idea of what package statements or whitespace you may not be posting with your code. Again, if you have similar questions in the future, please do so, as it will make helping you much easier.

Comment: eg, `accounts.add(account); // **** this is the offending line ****` Consider adding a "loud" comment or something like this in your posted code.

Comment: Ok, I will remember that in the future. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: My pleasure, and good luck. Now please accept Tenner's answer. :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels appreciate your willingness to teach and provide helpful feedback rather than blowing up at new people on SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to add an account without initializing the `ArrayList` in which they're stored. Add this to your `Customer` constructor.

```
this.accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Customer class, you declare an `ArrayList accounts`. Then, you have a method called `addAccount`, but it seems as though this `accounts` was never initialized.

Somewhere where you create your `Customer` object, you need to say:

```
newCustomer.accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

Comment: While this will work, it's probably not the best design decision. An object should generally take care of its own plumbing wherever possible. In this case there's no advantage to having an instantiator of a `Customer` be required to create an internal `ArrayList` before the instance can be used. In academic, single-developer environments, sure, whatever; but in a real-life application with multiple developers this is dangerous.

Comment: @Tenner agreed, your route is the best solution. You don't want to have to initialize a field for an object everytime you create a new object. I was figuring this was academic and was just trying to help him fix the problem in the least confusing manner.